# monacaで作成したアプリにプッシュ通知が届かない

Tags: javascript, ios, monaca, html

monacaで作成したアプリを審査に出して、iphoneのアプリストアに掲載されました。
それをダウンロードして、nifty mbaasを使ってプッシュ通知を送ったのですが、なぜか届きませんでした。
mbaasのプッシュ通知一覧では配信済み（一部エラー）と書かれており、数点は配信完了してますが、一部はできなかったという内容でした。もしかしたら、私の携帯は一部配信がされなかったのかもしれませんが。

なぜプッシュ通知がうまくいかなかったのか教えていただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

ちなみに掲載される前に、monacaでビルドをしてプッシュ通知を確認した時はちゃんと届いておりました。
そのため、mbaasにて必要とされるプッシュ通知の証明書は問題なく機能されている認識です。

エラー内容となります。

```
{
    "description": {
        "status": "complete"
    },
    "ios": {
        "total": 36,
        "complete": 30,
        "unknown": 2,
        "invalidToken": 4
    }
}
```

Comment: プッシュ通知の一覧で該当するプッシュ通知をクリックすると、右側に「配信エラー内容」が表示されます。その内容も掲載した方がよろしいかと思います。

Comment: エラー内容を追記ました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: iPhone版のリリース経験がないので推測でしか言えませんが、[iOS 9からAPNSデバイストークンがアプリインストールの度に変わるようになったようです](http://qiita.com/mono0926/items/9ef83c8b0de0e84118ac)が関係しているのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。
ios9からデバイストークンがアプリンストールの度に変わることを知らなかったです。これを元に原因を探していきたいと思います。